# Android Studio, Lanzar una notificación a dispositivos que tengan activado el canal de notificación

Tags: android-studio, sharedpreferences, android-notifications

Tengo en mi proyecto en un Fragment varios canales de notificación creados con preferences, lo que necesito saber es como lanzar notificaciones a través de esos canales de notificación, pero solo para los dispositivos que tengan los canales activados, si no están activados que no mande nada pero cada vez que mande una notificación solo lo reciban dichos dispositivos. Agradecería una ayudita porque en esta parte estoy un poco bloqueado sobre como hacerlo.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Generales">
        <SwitchPreferenceCompat
            android:key="españa"
            app:title="Notificar noticias españa"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_alert_black_24dp"
            />
        <SwitchPreferenceCompat
            android:key="deportes"
            app:title="Notificar noticias deportes"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_alert_black_24dp"
            />

    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Esta sería la forma que tengo para que los usuarios puedan activar o desactivar el canal de notificación.

Y en el fragment pongo las preference:

```js
public class Notificaciones extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public Notificaciones() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment Notificaciones.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static Notificaciones newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Notificaciones fragment = new Notificaciones();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notificaciones, container, false);

        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.contenedorNotificaciones,new CanalesFragment()).commit();

        return root;
    }
}
```

En el *main activity* recupero la configuración guardada así:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this,R.xml.preferencias,false);
```

Mi pregunta es yo al crear una noticia en mi aplicación quiero que se mande a través del canal que yo le diré cual es, pero que compruebe que usuarios tienen los canales activados o desactivados.

¿Alguien sabe como se haría?

Comment: Hola Daniel, como defines los canales y como activarían los canales los usuario?, considera agregar una explicación más amplia, recuerda revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: Hola Jorge, siguiendo tu recomendación aquí he dejado más información acerca de la pregunta, gracias por comentar